# LinkedIn member profile view doesn't work

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn's API for showing the full member profile has suddenly stopped working.
Using this syntax:

```
<script type="IN/FullMemberProfile" data-id="SOME LINKED ID"></script>
```

The returned page from LinkedIn says:

```
Your Request Could not be Completed.
```

Is this the cause of a temporary problem that LinkedIn is experiencing or a permanent change to LinkedIn's API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing at developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile

This works:
https://www.linkedin.com/in/yaneisimacias/?ppe=1

This doesn't:
https://www.linkedin.com/in/christineburrows2010/?ppe=1

Suggests to me it's a bug...?

Comment: Thanks for checking it out! Guess it is. Is there any way to get a response from LinkedIn?